# Restrict specific Entry Event type access to in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is anyone aware of any permissions we can use to restrict specific Entry Event types someone has access to in Journey Builder?
Our client is interested in limiting who could assemble a Salesforce Entry Event.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a permission available for the same. If available it will be under Administration 》Users 》select user 》Manage Roles 》Edit Permissions.